# Prove that if function f is monotonic, then it one-to-one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

What I have so far:

Suppose $f$ is monotonic. It is therefore either increasing or decreasing.

**Proof for increasing:**
If $f$ is increasing, then $f(x_1) <f(x_2)$ whenever $x_1 < x_2$, which means $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ if, and only if, $x_1 = x_2$.

Therefore $f$ is one to one.

I think this is wrong though. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: It's fine. You can add a sentence saying the proof is essentially the same when $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: This is exactly correct.  The key observation making the proof work is that $x<y\Rightarrow x\ne y$.  Similarly, $x>y\Rightarrow x\ne y$.

Comment: You're wrong: it's right :o) I just would simplify the proof using the other characterisation of one-to-one functions: if $\,x_1\neq x_2$, then $\,f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. For decreasing functions you may observe that if $f$ is decreasing, then $-f$ is increasing, and $f$ one-to-one is equivalent to $-f$ one-to-one.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a nice way to phrase the argument for $f$ increasing.

$$\begin{align}
f(x)=f(y) & \iff f(x)\le f(y)\text{ and }f(x)\ge f(y)\\
& \iff x\le y\text{ and }x\ge y\\
& \iff x=y.
\end{align}$$

Come to think of it. This exact argument works for $f$ decreasing.

Comment: A backslash is missing in your code.

Comment: Got it, thanks.